# Type casting for Core Data attribute setting

Tags: core-data, casting, nsstring, attributes, nsnumber

I am trying to set a Core Data attribute but am getting incompatible type errors. I have a float attribute in a Core Data entity on iPhone 3.0. Core Data auto-generates an interface for a managed data object that provides property access to it:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * volume;
```

and an implementation for it:

```
@dynamic volume;
```

I create an instance of the managed data object, which I call attrVolume, and use that to access that Core data entity attribute through a Core Data managed object context:

```
[attrVolume setVolume:[txtVolume.text floatValue]];
```

The compilation error is:

> incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setVolume:'

Any ideas how to cast that value and not get that compilation error? Is there a way to cast to NSNUmber?

Any help appreciated // :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-floatValue` returns a value of type `float`. You are then trying to set the value of `volume`, which takes an `NSNumber` to this `float` value, which fails.

You need to create an `NSNumber` from the float value of your string and assign that to `volume`:

```
NSNumber* volNum = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[textVolume.text floatValue]];
[attrVolume setVolume:volNum];
```